# Custom Native Modules does not appear in Native Modules

Tags: java, react-native, java-native-interface

I have created a custom native module similar to the one given in react-native docs. I have properly registered the native module. When I access it using the `NativeModules.CalendarModule;`, it gives a null output. Where am I going wrong?

MyAppPackage.java

```
package com.XXX; // replace your-app-name with your app’s name
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAppPackage implements ReactPackage {
   @Override
   public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
       return Collections.emptyList();
   }

   @Override
   public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
           ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
       List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

       modules.add(new CalendarModule(reactContext));

       return modules;
   }

}
```

CalendarModule.java

```
package com.xxx; // replace com.your-app-name with your app’s name
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CalendarModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    CalendarModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Calendar";
    }

}
```

MainApplication.java

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  packages.add(new MyAppPackage());
  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  return packages;
}
```

App.tsx

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { CalendarModule } = NativeModules;
console.log({ CalendarModule })
```

React-Native Version: 0.70